# using .join() based on condition in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to loop through the components array and join all the tire component descriptions with a comma (, ) if there are multiple.

```js
let dataForTemplate = {};
incident = {
  complaint_id: 55556473,
  components: [{
      component_id: 263,
      name: 'SEAT BELTS',
      description: '150000 SEAT BELTS',
      is_public: true,
      is_vehicle: true,
      is_equipment: false,
      is_tire: false,
      is_child_seat: false,
      is_active: true,
      is_deleted: false,
      risk_matrix_default_id: 1
    },
    {
      component_id: 300,
      name: 'TIRES',
      description: '190000 TIRES',
      is_public: true,
      is_vehicle: true,
      is_equipment: false,
      is_tire: true,
      is_child_seat: false,
      is_active: true,
      is_deleted: false,
      risk_matrix_default_id: 17
    },
    {
      component_id: 1025,
      name: 'CHILD SEAT:VEHICLE TETHER ANCHOR',
      description: '532000 CHILD SEAT:VEHICLE TETHER ANCHOR',
      is_public: true,
      is_vehicle: false,
      is_equipment: false,
      is_tire: false,
      is_child_seat: true,
      is_active: true,
      is_deleted: false,
      risk_matrix_default_id: 4
    }
  ]
};
```

Here is what I am trying:

```js
if (incident.components && incident.components.length > 0) {
  dataForTemplate.tire_components = incident.components.map((e) => {
    console.log(e);
    if (e.is_tire) {
      return ${e.description};
    }
  }).join(' ,');
}

console.log(dataForTemplate);
```

Current output: `{tire_components: " ,190000 TIRES ,"}`

Expected output: `{tire_components: "190000 TIRES"}`

It should only join string with comma if there are multiple descriptions satisfying the condition.

Comment: could be as easy as just replacing all occurrences of `:` with `,`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: The reason this doesn't work is that after your `map` call, you have an array of results, `["", "190000 TIRES", ""]`.  You want to `filter` first to include only the relevant ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter the array to get the `is_tire` entries, map tehm to get the description and join the result :

```js
let dataForTemplate = {};
incident = {
  complaint_id: 55556473,
  components: [
    {
      component_id: 263,
      name: "SEAT BELTS",
      description: "150000 SEAT BELTS",
      is_public: true,
      is_vehicle: true,
      is_equipment: false,
      is_tire: false,
      is_child_seat: false,
      is_active: true,
      is_deleted: false,
      risk_matrix_default_id: 1
    },
    {
      component_id: 300,
      name: "TIRES",
      description: "190000 TIRES",
      is_public: true,
      is_vehicle: true,
      is_equipment: false,
      is_tire: true,
      is_child_seat: false,
      is_active: true,
      is_deleted: false,
      risk_matrix_default_id: 17
    },
    {
      component_id: 1025,
      name: "CHILD SEAT:VEHICLE TETHER ANCHOR",
      description: "532000 CHILD SEAT:VEHICLE TETHER ANCHOR",
      is_public: true,
      is_vehicle: false,
      is_equipment: false,
      is_tire: false,
      is_child_seat: true,
      is_active: true,
      is_deleted: false,
      risk_matrix_default_id: 4
    }
  ]
};

if (incident.components && incident.components.length > 0) {
  dataForTemplate.tire_components = incident.components
    .filter(e => e.is_tire)
    .map(e => {
      return `${e.description}`;
    })
    .join(" ,");
}

console.log(dataForTemplate);
```

```js
let dataForTemplate = {};
incident = {
  complaint_id: 55556473,
  components: [
    {
      component_id: 263,
      name: "SEAT BELTS",
      description: "150000 SEAT BELTS",
      is_public: true,
      is_vehicle: true,
      is_equipment: false,
      is_tire: false,
      is_child_seat: false,
      is_active: true,
      is_deleted: false,
      risk_matrix_default_id: 1
    },
    {
      component_id: 300,
      name: "TIRES",
      description: "190000 TIRES",
      is_public: true,
      is_vehicle: true,
      is_equipment: false,
      is_tire: true,
      is_child_seat: false,
      is_active: true,
      is_deleted: false,
      risk_matrix_default_id: 17
    },
    {
      component_id: 300,
      name: "TIRES",
      description: "190000 TIRES example 2",
      is_public: true,
      is_vehicle: true,
      is_equipment: false,
      is_tire: true,
      is_child_seat: false,
      is_active: true,
      is_deleted: false,
      risk_matrix_default_id: 17
    },
    {
      component_id: 1025,
      name: "CHILD SEAT:VEHICLE TETHER ANCHOR",
      description: "532000 CHILD SEAT:VEHICLE TETHER ANCHOR",
      is_public: true,
      is_vehicle: false,
      is_equipment: false,
      is_tire: false,
      is_child_seat: true,
      is_active: true,
      is_deleted: false,
      risk_matrix_default_id: 4
    }
  ]
};

if (incident.components && incident.components.length > 0) {
  dataForTemplate.tire_components = incident.components
    .filter(e => e.is_tire)
    .map(e => {
      return `${e.description}`;
    })
    .join(" ,");
}

console.log(dataForTemplate);
```

Comment: The template literal seems unnecessary.

Comment: @JakeHolzinger i agree, but it was there in the OP's question and it's unrelated to the problem so i didn't change it.

Answer (score 1):

`Array.prototype.join` already does what you want, so it's just a matter of selecting the right data and calling `.join (', ')`.  Here's one technique:

```js
const tireComponentDescriptions = (incident) =>
  ((incident || {}) .components || [])
    .filter (i => i .is_tire)
    .map (i => i.description)
    .join (', ')
  

const incident = {complaint_id: 55556473, components: [{component_id: 263, name: "SEAT BELTS", description: "150000 SEAT BELTS", is_public: true, is_vehicle: true, is_equipment: false, is_tire: false, is_child_seat: false, is_active: true, is_deleted: false, risk_matrix_default_id: 1}, {component_id: 300, name: "TIRES", description: "190000 TIRES", is_public: true, is_vehicle: true, is_equipment: false, is_tire: true, is_child_seat: false, is_active: true, is_deleted: false, risk_matrix_default_id: 17}, {component_id: 1025, name: "CHILD SEAT: VEHICLE TETHER ANCHOR", description: "532000 CHILD SEAT: VEHICLE TETHER ANCHOR", is_public: true, is_vehicle: false, is_equipment: false, is_tire: false, is_child_seat: true, is_active: true, is_deleted: false, risk_matrix_default_id: 4}]};

console .log (tireComponentDescriptions (incident))

incident .components [0] .is_tire = true
console .log (tireComponentDescriptions (incident))

incident .components [2] .is_tire = true
console .log (tireComponentDescriptions (incident))
```

Answer (score 0):

filter through the components, map to the description and join the resulting array afterwards
`components.filter(component => component.is_tire).map(component => component.description).join(', ')`

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` always returns an array of the same length, so will contain undefined values in your example.  You could use `Array.filter` to first filter out any values you don't want before using `join`

```
if (incident.components && incident.components.length > 0) {
    dataForTemplate.tire_components = incident.components.filter(e => e.is_tire).map(e => e.description).join(' ,');
}
```

You could also use `Array.reduce` to filter and map at the same time.

```
if (incident.components && incident.components.length > 0) {
    dataForTemplate.tire_components = incident.components.reduce((output, e) => {
      if(e.is_tire) { 
        output.push(e.description) 
      } 
      return output
    }, []).join(' ,');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter in advance and then map the wanted property.

```js
let dataForTemplate = {},
    incident = { complaint_id: 55556473, components: [{ component_id: 263, name: "SEAT BELTS", description: "150000 SEAT BELTS", is_public: true, is_vehicle: true, is_equipment: false, is_tire: false, is_child_seat: false, is_active: true, is_deleted: false, risk_matrix_default_id: 1 }, { component_id: 300, name: "TIRES", description: "190000 TIRES", is_public: true, is_vehicle: true, is_equipment: false, is_tire: true, is_child_seat: false, is_active: true, is_deleted: false, risk_matrix_default_id: 17 }, { component_id: 1025, name: "CHILD SEAT:VEHICLE TETHER ANCHOR", description: "532000 CHILD SEAT:VEHICLE TETHER ANCHOR", is_public: true, is_vehicle: false, is_equipment: false, is_tire: false, is_child_seat: true, is_active: true, is_deleted: false, risk_matrix_default_id: 4 }] };

if (incident.components && incident.components.length > 0) {
    dataForTemplate.tire_components = incident.components
        .filter(({ is_tire }) => is_tire)
        .map(({ description }) => description)
        .join(' ,');
}

console.log(dataForTemplate);
```